# Do not want to show the exact location with Google Map in my Android app

Tags: android, android-maps

This might be a bit off-topic. But I have been searching a lot for this and could not find anything.

I am developing an app, which would show to the user the near-by activities happening based on his current location. The client wants to show all the near-by activities in a map like view. But the issue is that he does not want to show the exact locations of the activities, due to privacy issues. Just a rough view of the things happening around in a map would be ideal.

Is it possible to prevent showing the exact details using a google map. Is there any alternate visual representation for this scenario.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may send to Android application a `LatLng` that is randomized and accuracy value in meters. This way you can represent an activity using `Circle` class with optional `Marker` in the center, so you can get info windows easily.

Comment: Thanks.. I can give this a try. Do you have any link which explains this in more detail. I can study that and get more understanding about it. Also, one more thing I was considering is to use Google Charts api to develop some sort of chart.. just thinking about it if it is feasible..